# Can JAXB unmarshal a string into a date attribute

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a xml tag in this format:

```
<DOB>19801213</DOB>
```

How can I unmarshal this xml tag into a Date variable?

```
@XmlElement (name = "DOB")
private Date dob
```

When I try to get dob it return me null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use an `XmlAdapter`

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {

    @Override
    public String marshal(Date v) throws Exception {
        return .. ;
    }

    @Override
    public Date unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return .. ;
    }

}
```

and on your attribute you must add `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
@XmlElement (name = "DOB")
private Date dob;
```

Comment: So when the return I can do the conversion from YYYYMMDD to Date format and from date formate to string YYYYMMDD?